# Disable WinRM after Packer Build

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, devops, packer

The question has probably been asked before, but I couldn't find a reference. I am using packer to build custom Windows AWS AMI. After the packer build, I provisioned an EC2 instance using the AMI and noticed WinRM service is running and the Firewall rule I had set in user_data is also enabled. I don't want that to be part of my image build. How to get around it?
Here is my packer template:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "ami_region": "us-east-1",
        "build_version": "{{isotime \"2006.01.02.150405\"}}",
        "aws_vpc": "vpc-0cf252de620488ef2",
        "vpc_subnet": "subnet-06909f11bbb49a814"
    },
    "builders": [
        {
            "type": "amazon-ebs",
            "profile": "default",
            "region": "{{user `ami_region`}}",
            "vpc_id": "{{user `aws_vpc`}}",
            "subnet_id": "{{user `vpc_subnet`}}",
            "source_ami_filter": {
                "filters": {
                    "virtualization-type": "hvm",
                    "name": "Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-Base*",
                    "root-device-type": "ebs"
                },
                "owners": [
                    "amazon"
                ],
                "most_recent": true
            },
            "ami_name": "WIN2016-CUSTOM-{{user `build_version`}}",
            "instance_type": "t3.medium",
            "associate_public_ip_address": true,
            "user_data_file": "C:\\Users\\amita\\Documents\\DevOps\\AWS\\packer\\winrm.ps1",
            "communicator": "winrm",
            "winrm_username": "Administrator",
            "winrm_port": 5986,
            "winrm_timeout": "15m",
            "winrm_use_ssl": true,
            "winrm_insecure": true
        }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "powershell",
            "script": "C:\\Users\\amita\\Documents\\DevOps\\AWS\\packer\\Install-Apps.ps1"
        },
        {
            "type": "windows-restart",
            "restart_check_command": "powershell -command \"& {Write-Output 'restarted.'}\""
        },
        {
            "type": "powershell",
            "inline": [
                "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\EC2-Windows\\Launch\\Scripts\\InitializeInstance.ps1 -Schedule",
                "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\EC2-Windows\\Launch\\Scripts\\SysprepInstance.ps1 -NoShutdown"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

User-Data

```
<powershell>
write-output "Running User Data Script"
write-host "(host) Running User Data Script"

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

# Remove HTTP listener
Remove-Item -Path WSMan:\Localhost\listener\listener* -Recurse

# Create self-signed certificate
$Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertstoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "packer"
New-Item -Path WSMan:\LocalHost\Listener -Transport HTTPS -Address * -CertificateThumbPrint $Cert.Thumbprint -Force

# WinRM
write-output "Setting up WinRM"
write-host "(host) setting up WinRM"
# Configure WinRM
cmd.exe /c winrm quickconfig -q
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config" '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/winrs" '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="1024"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/service" '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/client" '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/service/auth" '@{Basic="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/client/auth" '@{Basic="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/service/auth" '@{CredSSP="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS" "@{Port=`"5986`";Hostname=`"packer`";CertificateThumbprint=`"$($Cert.Thumbprint)`"}"
cmd.exe /c netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote administration" new enable=yes
cmd.exe /c netsh firewall add portopening TCP 5986 "WinRM_HTTPS"
cmd.exe /c net stop winrm
cmd.exe /c sc config winrm start= auto
cmd.exe /c net start winrm
</powershell>
```

Comment: This article by Matthew Hodgkins is what I use: https://hodgkins.io/best-practices-with-packer-and-windows#disable-winrm-on-build-completion-and-only-enable-it-on-first-boot In summary create a shutdown script which blocks WinRM and then syspreps the image.